# What are some heuristics for choosing a diff algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, diff

The Myers diff algorithm performs well when the differences between the two texts are small, because most simple implementations have complexity O((N+M) * D). However when differences are large, it takes a very long time to run. For example, if one of the texts is large and the other is the empty string, many implementations take several minutes to run.

If you knew the differences were large, then you could choose a different algorithm. How do diff tools make this determination in practice?

Comment: One nice feature of Myers's algorithm is that you loop over increasing values of d, testing whether the current value of d is large enough -- so you can simply exit early if you reach a d that you deem "too high".